# CAPICOM and X509

Tags: x509certificate2, capicom

I have a web application form. The aim is to create a xml of data from web form and sign it with the user usb certificate.
I am using CAPICOM.store to successfully open all user certificate. When I click on one that I want I exported it. After that I am importing selected certificate in X509Cetificate2 to sign xml. But in my code I am getting error on line 
signedXml.ComputeSignature() and message is 'Signing key is not loaded.' Please any help or suggestion to fix this.

```
    Function SignXML(uppXML As String) As String

    Dim bResult As Boolean = False
    Dim pCertContext As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = Nothing
    Dim signedXml As SignedXml = Nothing
    Dim reference As Reference = Nothing
    Dim trns As XmlDsigC14NTransform = Nothing
    Dim env As XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform = Nothing
    Dim keyInfo As KeyInfo = Nothing
    Dim xmlDigitalSignature As XmlElement = Nothing 

    Dim hideFiledCapicom As String = Replace(txtCapicom.Text, " ", "+")
    Dim certificate As New X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(hideFiledCapicom)) 
        Dim key As AsymmetricAlgorithm = certificate.PrivateKey

        doc = New XmlDocument
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = True
        doc.LoadXml(uppXML)

        signedXml = New SignedXml(doc)
        signedXml.SigningKey = key

        reference = New Reference
        reference.Uri = ""

        trns = New XmlDsigC14NTransform

        reference.AddTransform(trns)

        env = New XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform

        reference.AddTransform(env)

        signedXml.AddReference(reference)

        keyInfo = New KeyInfo()
        keyInfo.AddClause(New KeyInfoX509Data(certificate))

        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo
        signedXml.ComputeSignature()

        xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml()

        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, True))

        If TypeOf doc.FirstChild Is XmlDeclaration Then
            doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild)
        End If

        uppXML = doc.OuterXml

    Return uppXML

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this.

In JavaScript where I use CAPICOM to choose and export certificate I am also getting and the private key from certificate and putting it in hidden fields.

```
 var privateKey = certificates.Item(1).PrivateKey.KeySpec

 var exportKey = document.getElementById("<%=hideFieldKey.ClientID%>");
     exportKey = privateKey
     document.getElementById('HiddenKey').value = exportKey;
```

In my vb code I use CspParameters() to get private key and RSACryptoServiceProvider() to proceed further for signing xml document.